# Display data in a database based on the current month

Tags: php, mysql

Im making system information about cash manager

i try with datenow and filtering but fail.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$no = 1;
$sql = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM tb_kas WHERE jenis = 'masuk' ");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

?>
```

i expect the output is by month but its viewing all data...

Comment: *"i try with datenow and filtering"* Where ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_kas
WHERE jenis = 'masuk' AND (MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
```